# Assertion `s < d_bufsize' failed

Tags: c++, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to build a sync block with Kurtosis capability using gr_modtool.

I used to make them with sink blocks, but decided to remake them with sync blocks.

The code itself can be compiled without error.

But when I run the flow graph in GRC, it produces following error message.

It appears when you try to return the number of items consumed.

Question: How to solve this error?

Thank you in advance for any guidance you may be able to provide.

```
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_c.block.yml
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform.block_loader:Block with id "Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p" loaded from
  /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml
overwritten by
  /usr/local/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/Kurtosis_Kurtosis_p.block.yml

Generating: '/home/nomo/j.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/nomo/j.py

0
7
python3: ../gnuradio-runtime/lib/../include/gnuradio/buffer.h:193: unsigned int gr::buffer::index_add(unsigned int, unsigned int): Assertion `s < d_bufsize' failed.
```

Below is the implmentation source file:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "Kurtosis_only_c_impl.h"

namespace gr {
  namespace Kurtosis_only {

    using input_type = gr_complex;
    using output_type = gr_complex;
    
    
    
    Kurtosis_only_c::sptr
    Kurtosis_only_c::make(int large_loop, int small_loop)
    {
      return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
        (new Kurtosis_only_c_impl(large_loop, small_loop));
    }


    /*
     * The private constructor
     */
    Kurtosis_only_c_impl::Kurtosis_only_c_impl(int large_loop, int small_loop)
      : gr::sync_block("Kurtosis_only_c",
              gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(input_type) * small_loop),
              gr::io_signature::make(2, 2, sizeof(output_type) * small_loop)),
              d_LL(large_loop), d_SL(small_loop)
    {
      
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Our virtual destructor.
     */
    Kurtosis_only_c_impl::~Kurtosis_only_c_impl()
    {
    }

    void Kurtosis_only_c_impl::forecast(int noutput_items, gr_vector_int &ninput_items_required)
    {
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ninput_items_required.size(); ++i) 
        ninput_items_required[i] = d_SL;
    }

    int
    Kurtosis_only_c_impl::work(int noutput_items,
        gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
        gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
    {
    
      /*printf("sizeof(gr_compelx) = %ld", sizeof(gr_complex));
      printf("sizeof(gr_complex) * small_loop = %ld", sizeof(gr_complex) * d_SL);

       printf("in0 = %d, out0 = %d", input_items, output_items);
       
       printf("d_N = %d", d_SL);*/
        
      auto in0  = static_cast<const input_type*>(input_items[0]);
      auto out0 = static_cast<output_type*>(output_items[0]);
      auto out1 = static_cast<output_type*>(output_items[1]);
      
     
      
      gr_complex S1r[d_SL], S1i[d_SL], S2r[d_SL], S2i[d_SL], S3r[d_SL], S3i[d_SL], 
                 S4r[d_SL], S4i[d_SL];
                           
      gr_complex dcnt[d_SL];
      
      gr_complex Myu1r[d_SL], Myu1i[d_SL], Myu2r[d_SL], Myu2i[d_SL], Myu3r[d_SL], 
                 Myu3i[d_SL], Myu4r[d_SL], Myu4i[d_SL];
      
      gr_complex M1r[d_SL], M1i[d_SL], M2r[d_SL], M2i[d_SL], M3r[d_SL], M3i[d_SL], M4r[d_SL], 
                 M4i[d_SL];
                           
      gr_complex Kr[d_SL], Ki[d_SL];
      
     /*for (int k = 0; k < noutput_items; k += d_SL)
      {
        unsigned int datasize = noutput_items - k;
        unsigned int resid = d_SL - d_index;*/

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < d_LL; ++j)
        {
          
          for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d_SL; ++i)
          {
            pwr =  in0[i].real();
            pwi =  in0[i].imag();
        
            S1r[i]  += pwr;
            S1i[i]  += pwi;
        
            S2r[i]  += pwr * pwr;
            S2i[i]  += pwi * pwi;
        
        S3r[i]  += pwr * pwr * pwr;
        S3i[i]  += pwi * pwi * pwi;
        
        S4r[i]  += pwr * pwr * pwr * pwr;
        S4i[i]  += pwi * pwi * pwi * pwi;
        
        dcnt[i] += 1;    
          }
        }   
      
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d_SL; ++i)
        {
          Myu1r[i] = S1r[i] / dcnt[i];
          Myu1i[i] = S1i[i] / dcnt[i];
      
          Myu2r[i] = S2r[i] / dcnt[i];
          Myu2i[i] = S2i[i] / dcnt[i];
      
          Myu3r[i] = S3r[i] / dcnt[i];
          Myu3i[i] = S3i[i] / dcnt[i];
      
          Myu4r[i] = S4r[i] / dcnt[i];
          Myu4i[i] = S4i[i] / dcnt[i];
        }


        gr_complex a = 4, b = 6, c = 3, d = 2;
        
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d_SL; ++i)
        {
          M1r[i] = a * Myu3r[i] * Myu1r[i];
          M1i[i] = a * Myu3i[i] * Myu1i[i];
          
          M2r[i] = b * Myu2r[i] * pow(Myu1r[i], d);
          M2i[i] = b * Myu2i[i] * pow(Myu1i[i], d);
          
          M3r[i] = c * pow(Myu1r[i], a);
          M3i[i] = c * pow(Myu1i[i], a);
          
          M4r[i] = Myu2r[i] - pow(Myu1r[i], d);
          M4i[i] = Myu2i[i] - pow(Myu1i[i], d);
        }
          
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d_SL; ++i)
        {     
          Kr[i] = (Myu4r[i] - M1r[i] + M2r[i] - M3r[i]) / pow(M4r[i], d);
      
          Ki[i] = (Myu4i[i] - M1i[i] + M2i[i] - M3i[i]) / pow(M4i[i], d);
        }
          
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < d_SL; ++i)
        {
          out0[i] = Kr[i];
          out1[i] = Ki[i];
        }
        
      
        
      return 0;
    
    }
  } /* namespace Kurtosis_only */
} /* namespace gr */
```

Below is the header file.

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_KURTOSIS_ONLY_KURTOSIS_ONLY_C_IMPL_H
#define INCLUDED_KURTOSIS_ONLY_KURTOSIS_ONLY_C_IMPL_H

#include <Kurtosis_only/Kurtosis_only_c.h>

namespace gr {
  namespace Kurtosis_only {

    class Kurtosis_only_c_impl : public Kurtosis_only_c
    {
     private:
       gr_complex pwr;
       gr_complex pwi;
       
       int d_LL;
       int d_SL;
       
       int d_index = 0;
       
     public:
      Kurtosis_only_c_impl(int large_loop, int small_loop);
      ~Kurtosis_only_c_impl();
      
      void forecast(int nouput_items, gr_vector_int &ninput_items_required) override;
      
      // Where all the action really happens
      int work(
              int noutput_items,
              gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
              gr_vector_void_star &output_items
      );
      
      
    };

     
  } // namespace Kurtosis_only
} // namespace gr

#endif /* INCLUDED_KURTOSIS_ONLY_KURTOSIS_ONLY_C_IMPL_H */
```

Below is the flow graph in GRC.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming you can simply produce and consume `d_SL` items. That is not generally the case. As explained in the comments to my previous answer (and at the end of said answer), you need to **check** whether you have enough in- and output space.

Comment: Thank you again for your response.I did what you advised me to do, but I am not sure again, so I asked a question.I checked the number of `noutput_items` and it is either 3 or 4.Since I have set `d_SL=1024`, it dose not become  `noutput_items >= d_SL`...

Comment: well, if `noutput_items < d_SL` you simply cannot work and have to `return 0;` immediately. So, you need to implement the `forecast` method to tell the scheduler you need `d_SL` items!

Comment: I must apologize for the delay in my reply. I changed it to return 0, implemented the forecast function and edited the source file. However, it does not work...

Comment: Is it the same problem as you describe above? Because that error literally says you're consuming or producing more than the actually available buffer allows, so something still goes wrong with checking.

Comment: wait, you just now generally `return 0;`. That makes no sense. Please go back and *understand* what it means to return a value.

Comment: I am very sorry for the delay in replying. I was preparing for an exam and failed to reply. I still haven't resolved, but I will think about it again.